# how to calculate rolling mean for 7 days in the future in R

Tags: r

looking to expand my rolling mean to the next days, to forecast the COVID-19 new cases by country + transportation type for dates in the future.

I used this:

```
dffinal <- dffinal %>%
  dplyr::arrange(variable) %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(region, transportation_type) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(new_cases_rolling = zoo::rollapply(new_cases, 3, mean,fill = NA, align = "right")) %>% 
  dplyr::ungroup()
```

but it only calculate for the dates I have the information.
I would like to take the lase 3 days and calculate the next day, and than go on

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Your subject says *"7 days in the future"* and the body of your question says *"lase [sic] 3 days and calculate the next day"*, please clear up that contradiction. And I second RonakShah's comment: I see no reason why this won't function, so you need to demonstrate (with *usable sample data*) what is happening and why it is not what you expect.